# I can convert a byte array to Bitmap but the same process in reverse produces a null

Tags: java, android, bitmap, android-bitmap

So I have a byte array which I can covert to bitmap using the below function:

```
private Bitmap getBitMapFromByte(byte[] imageByte) {
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageByte, 0, imageByte.length);
        return bitmap;
    }
```

This produces the correct result and I can preview the returned bitmap in debug viewer.

I then have some intermediate functions that require the image to be in a byte array `byte[]`. So I convert the bitmap to `byte[]` using:

```
int byteCount = myBitmapImage.getAllocationByteCount();
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(byteCount); //Create a new buffer
myBitmapImage.copyPixelsToBuffer(buffer); //Move the byte data to the buffer
byte[] myByte = buffer.array();
```

Now the same byte array converted immediately back to bitmap produces a null

```
Bitmap testBitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(myByte, 0, myByte.length);
```

Why is a bytearray immediately converted back to bitmap returning null?

Comment: ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); bitmap.compress ( jpeg , .. baos); byte bytes []= baos.toByteArray(); (please look up the right parameters and names ;-)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert Bitmap to Byte Array use the following code

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
```

To convert Byte Array to bitmap use following code

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, bitmapdata.length);
```